# how do you make commands not show up on the chat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a server, and I put a comparitor clock down to constantly have clear weather. How do I silence the commands?

Answer (score 17):

You can use the following command to do this:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

Comment: I believe in the newest snapshot (14w26c, I think) you can toggle the output of the command block whether or not you have the gamerule disabled. To the right of the "last output" box, there is a button which toggles between X and O. I have yet to test it.

Comment: the X doesn't seem to do that.